# Winsocks recv just one line

Tags: c++, winsock, getline

I'm pretty new to c++ and trying some sockets programming. My problem with this is, that i can't get `x = recv((SOCKET)this->sock, ausgabe, 1000, 0);` to only return one line at a time, the lines are splitted by `\n\r`.

i've tried stuff like:

```
        char * pos;
        pos = strstr(ausgabe, "\n");
        while(pos != NULL){
            std::cout<< pos;
            pos = strstr(pos, "\n");
        }
```

but this would not work as expected. I hope you know this problem and got a solution to help me.

Greetings,
Frederick

Comment: You want to read from the socket until you get a \n\r or you want to parse the message and split on \n\r?

Comment: the best way would be to read it until i get a \n\r. the splitting was another way i tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use token library:

```
#include <string.h>
.
.
char *line = strtok(ausgabe,"\n");
while (line != NULL)
{
    line[strlen(line)-1] = '\0';    // if newline character is \r\n
    cout << line;
    line = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    // line++; // ignore \r         // if newline character is \n\r
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/DYL1bjtb

For more information on tokenization http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/

Comment: this doesn't give me any compiler errors or warnings, but instantly crashes as soon as my programm reaches this point :D

Comment: you specified that the newline characters are \n\r while I wonder it should be \n\r if that's the case then above should be modifed a little

Comment: see the updated code if newline character is \r\n, it should work

Comment: is there a way to start a second instance of `strtok`, to split `line` inside of the "parent" `strtok`?

Comment: no, you cannot start multiple instance of strtok at a time. If you want to start tokenizing another string you can do so by passing that string as first argument to strtok but then previous instance of strtok would be lost

Comment: so whats best practice to do so? is their some king of regex implementation without getting a lot overhead using big libarys?

Answer (score 2):

You can read one byte at a time and check for '\r\n', but it is horribly inefficient.

You should always read as many bytes as you can from a socket to a buffer, and then parse you buffer using your strstr().

Is is a datagram socket like UDP or stream socket like TCP? They are different.

Comment: i'm using a tcp connection in my socket